# Offsetting my parallax issue

Tags: javascript

I'm really struggling with the maths behind my multilayer parallax. If I have the parallax effect at the top of the page then it works fine, however, due it potentially being anywhere on my page I need to offset the parallax and adjust the height so you don't see the background.

However, I need to work out how much I need to adjust the size of the layers, based on the depth the layer has and where it's positioned on the page. This parallax panel could be anywhere on the page, however.

Here is my code and a working example:

```js
/**
 * @author Martyn Lee Ball
 * @desc Creates multi-layer Parallax effect
 * @version 1.0
 * @return {Array} Returns instances of classes as Array
 */
;class Parallax {

    constructor(node) {
        const self = this;

        // Settings and defaults
        self.settings = {
            container: node,
            height: node.clientHeight,
            name: node.dataset.parallax,
            layers: [],
            defaultDepth: 0.5,
            offset: function(element) {
                let top = 0, left = 0;
                do {
                    top += element.offsetTop  || 0;
                    left += element.offsetLeft || 0;
                    element = element.offsetParent;
                } while(element);

                return {
                    top: top,
                    left: left
                };
            }.call(self, node)
        }
        ;

        // Populate layers setting with objects
        (function() {
            let layers = (self.settings.container).querySelectorAll('[data-layer]');
            let count = 0;
            for (const layer in layers) {
                if (layers.hasOwnProperty(layer)) {
                    self.settings.layers.push({
                        // Get the depth, set to default depth if not set
                        depth: (function() {
                            if (layers[layer].dataset.depth !== undefined)
                                return parseFloat(layers[layer].dataset.depth);
                            return self.settings.defaultDepth;
                        }.call(self)),
                        element: layers[layer],
                        name: layers[layer].dataset.layer,
                    });

                    let height = function(layer) {
                        const self = this;
                        let height = self.settings.height;
                        return (height + (height - (height * layer.depth)));
                    }.call(self, self.settings.layers[count]);

                    layers[layer].style.height = height + "px";

                }
                count++;
            }
        }.call(this));

        this.setupScrollEvent.call(this);
    }

    setupScrollEvent() {
        const self = this;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
            self.last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            if (!self.ticking) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    self.scrolledEvent.call(self, self.last_known_scroll_position);
                    self.ticking = false;
                });
                self.ticking = true;
            }
        });
        self.last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        self.scrolledEvent.call(self, self.last_known_scroll_position);
    }

    scrolledEvent(scrollY) {
        const self = this;

        // TODO: Check panel is in view

        for (const layer in self.settings.layers) {
            if ((self.settings.layers).hasOwnProperty(layer)) {

                let movement = -((scrollY * self.settings.layers[layer].depth) - scrollY);
                let translate3d = 'translate3d(0, ' + movement + 'px, 0)';

                self.settings.layers[layer].element.style['-webkit-transform'] = translate3d;
                self.settings.layers[layer].element.style['-moz-transform'] = translate3d;
                self.settings.layers[layer].element.style['-ms-transform'] = translate3d;
                self.settings.layers[layer].element.style['-o-transform'] = translate3d;
                self.settings.layers[layer].element.style.transform = translate3d;
            }
        }
    }

    static initialize() {

        this.instances = [];

        // Ensure DOM has loaded
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Does page contain any parallax panels?
            let panels = document.querySelectorAll('[data-parallax]');
            if (panels.length > 0) {

                // Parallax panels found, create instances of class and return them for reference
                for (const panel in panels) {
                    if (panels.hasOwnProperty(panel)) {
                        this.instances.push(new this(panels[panel]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));

        return this.instances;
    }
}


window.plugins = { "parallax-instances": Parallax.initialize() };
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.layer {
  height: 800px;
}
section[data-parallax] {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
}
section[data-parallax] > div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-bg'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/F7pqpWZ.jpg');
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-1'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/uxpVhe1.png');
  background-position: left bottom;
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-2'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/JeGChIm.png');
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-3'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/V7l8cxD.png');
  background-position: right bottom;
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-4'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/joB5tI4.png');
}
section[data-parallax] > div[data-layer='layer-overlay'] {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/h1ybMNZ.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Parallax Development</title>
        <script src="parallax-dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section style="padding-top: 300px;"></section>
        <section data-parallax="panel-1">
            <div data-layer="layer-bg" data-depth="0.10"></div>
            <div data-layer="layer-1" data-depth="0.20"></div>
            <div data-layer="layer-2" data-depth="0.50"></div>
            <div data-layer="layer-3" data-depth="0.80"></div>
            <div data-layer="layer-4" data-depth="1.0"></div>
        </section>
        <section style="padding-bottom: 50vh;"></section>

    </body>
</html>
```